# Migrate VHDL to EE StackExchange

Tags: discussion, tags, duplicate-questions

A question was posted on both StackOverflow and Electronics StackExchange.

[https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116050/entries-for-subprograms-in-vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320935/entries-for-subprograms-in-vhdl)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320935/entries-for-subprograms-in-vhdl

However, both have VHDL tags.

- [EE vhdl](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) => 338 questions
- [SO vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) => 1643 questions

As an EE myself, I would say VHDL belongs on electronics.  But it's hard to blame the asker; as an answer came back on SO faster than EE.

Having both tags on both sites just seems like a bad idea.  It seems to me that if EE.SE has graduated beta then the VHDL questions belong there.  After all, it is a **Hardware Description Language** and an IEEE standard.

Comment: There is naturally overlap between the various Stack Exchange sites. People tell me that this is not a problem, even though it violates my natural tendency to keep everything separated and well-ordered.

Comment: You can likely separate questions into two groups, those on VHDL language usage itself and those asking on practical usage (generating hardware) falling along the lines of SO and EE with some overlap. Standards versus vendor tools (and yes historically there was a standard concerning synthesis it' effects are still felt).  As an EE myself I don't see a dichotomy in need of fixing, after all it's a language and has compilers (analyzers), linkers (elaboration) and run time environments (simulators).

Comment: Actually I've been in this position "hmm where to ask VHDL questions". But as I saw the tag on stackoverflow I asked here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not that the same tag exists on multiple sites - that's perfectly acceptable - but the OP has asked the same *question* on two sites.

The correct solution here is to leave open the one where it's most on-topic or will get the best answers and then close the other one. It's only worth migrating and then merging a question if it has answers on both sites.

In the case where the question has answers on the less relevant site it's probably best to flag the question on the more relevant site so that that site's moderators can request migration and then merge the questions. What we don't want to to migrate the question and then the target site have two copies of the question open for an extended period.

Comment: Regardless of whether the same tag exists on multiple sites or not, the problem is the lack of a criteria for determining when it would be on topic on one vs. the other.  I can't think of a reasonable way of discerning when a VHDL question is a "StackOverflow VHDL question" or an "Electronics VHDL question".  Looking through the questions can you suggest a way of making that discernment for future questioners to know where their post will be most "on topic"?  If it is purely a numbers game, it seems like a savvy asker would only ask on SO.

Comment: @Hostile you may reach more people on SO, but if you need an answer from the perspective of an electronics engineer, you stand to get a better answer on EE.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - You'd likely find that both are used for basic questions that shouldn't be asked as a first resort on either. Providing answers on both EE appears to be used more for vendor tool problems (practical application) while SO is more about VHDL language issues (expressing designs) in keeping with site intent. I answer questions on both as a driver to improve standard understanding for tool development by analyzing questions using the IEEE standard(s).